# How to write a macro in Excel that will hardcode all the cells in a workbook that contain formulas with the letter "CIQ"?

Tags: excel, hardcode, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet that is pulling a lot of data from Capital IQ (CIQ). I would like to hardcode all these formulas. If somebody that doesn't have the CIQ plugin tries to look at the spreadsheet, all they see is #name and #value. I don't want to hardcode all the cells since some of them are useful to see how they are linked to other tabs. I am looking to hardcode only the cells that contain a CIQ formula. 
Thank you for your help!
Miha

Comment: It's too bad you failed to make even the slightest attempt.

Comment: I tried and I failed, hence I am asking here

Comment: @MihaelaCiulianu The code of yourself - that is all are waiting from you :)

Answer (score 1):

Untested from mobile

```
Sub find()
     Dim c as range
     For each c in range(“A1:B100”).Cells
        On Error Resume Next
        If application.worksheetFunction. Search(c.value,”CIQ”) > 0 then c = c.value
     Next c
End sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I'll check it out and let you know if it solves my problem

Comment: @MihaelaCiulianu make sure to change the range to what range your iterating through

Comment: If this solved your question, please mark as answered so other users will know it is closed